# How to access characters within a list of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

Is there a direct way (not using a loop) of accessing the different characters of the strings that form a list?

For example:

```
L=['hola','que','tal']
```

How would I directly access for example to the second element of the third string? [i.e. 'a']. In the same line, how would I directly access to the first two elements of each string to create the new list

```
S=['ho','qu','ta']
```

I would expect something like `L[2][1]` in the first case and similarly `L[:][:2]` but it is obviously incorrect.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `L[2][1]`. It returns `'a'`.

Comment: this question contains 2 questions. That's not complying to [ask]

Comment: You can't do it without some loop-like construction, so either an explicit loop, a `map` operation, some form of comprehension... essentially, python slice syntax doesn't work the way you'd like with `list` and `str` types.

Answer (score 3):

Your first approach is correct, that is indeed how you index a multidimensional list

```
>>> L[2][1]
'a'
```

The second problem can be solved using slicing within a list comprehension

```
>>> [i[:2] for i in L]
['ho', 'qu', 'ta']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
[a[:2] for a in L]
```

---

```
>>> L
['hola', 'que', 'tal']
>>> [a[:2] for a in L]
['ho', 'qu', 'ta']
```

We're iterating on the list `L`, and for each element we get the first two characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension for this:

```
L=['hola','que','tal']
s = [i[:2] for i in L]
```

This give you:

```
['ho', 'qu', 'ta']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first two elements of each string in a new list use this:

```
L=['hola','que','tal']
S = [x[:2] for x in L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to get that output without using a loop (waiting for someone to prove me wrong). You could *hide* the loop using `map()`:

```
L=['hola','que','tal']
print(map(lambda x: x[:2], L))
#['ho', 'qu', 'ta']
```